# nfs mount fails from Finder though works from command line

Tags: macos, network, mount, nfs

[image: NFS mounting from OSX]

Using Finder's Connect to Server... option with `nfs://vers=4;nuc.local/mnt/tb` I'm unable to mount my nfs server. However from the command line it works just fine.

Ideally I want the MBP to boot and mount the share when at home automatically. However I'm struggling to understand auto mounting on MacOSX 10.10.4. Can someone please additionally illustrate IIUC a `/etc/auto_master` example?

nuc.local's `/etc/exports` is:

```
/mnt/tb     *(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: This looks like the problems I am having: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4691244?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

To properly connect to NFSv4 share with the Finder use `nfs://vers=4,nuc.local/mnt/tb` instead of `nfs://vers=4;nuc.local/mnt/tb`.

To mount a share automatically do the following:

- Create a folder (e.g. /Users/youruser/mnt) as the future mount point
- Open Terminal and enter `sudo nano /etc/auto_master`
- Add a line with the following content:

  > /Users/youruser/mnt /etc/auto_nfs

  Please check, that the file contains a trailing empty line!
  Save the edit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and quit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
- enter `sudo touch /etc/auto_nfs` to create a new file with the name "auto_nfs".
- Enter  `sudo nano /etc/auto_nfs` to edit the file.
- Add a line with the following content:

  > DirectoryName -fstype=nfs,other_options... exported_share

  Please check, that the file contains a trailing empty line!
  Save the edit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and quit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
- Enter `sudo automount -vc` to mount the new NFS-share immediately.

Example (mount an external iTunes Media folder to local /Users/someusername/mnt):

auto_master:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/Users/someusername/mnt /etc/auto_nfs
```

auto_nfs:

```
iTunesMedia -fstype=nfs,rw,bg,hard,intr,tcp 192.168.2.11:/volume1/iTunesMedia
```

Tested with 10.7.5 and 10.10.4

---

After some extended testing with a virtual ArchLinux VM as NFS-server and Mac OS 10.10.4 as the NFS-client I come to the following conclusion:

The Finder probably has a bug connecting to NFSv4-only NFS-servers (ArchLinux).
So if you have disabled NFSv2/NFSv3 in /etc/conf.d/nfs-server.conf you won't be able to connect to the NFS-Share with the Finder.

You will be able to connect to it with `mount_nfs options server.local:/share /destination..` or [NFS Manager](http://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html) though.

If you enable NFSv2/NFSv3 you will be able to connect to the share with the Finder if you use the full path (as defined in exports) to the share: `nfs://vers=4,server.local/path/to/share`.

Comment: I tried your automounter suggestion and I keep just getting: "NFS server nuc.local not responding". I tried replacing it with it's IP address. No dice. Furthermore this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG3sV85SYeo

Comment: @hendry What kind of OS is installed on nuc.local? ArchLinux?

Comment: That's correct, Archlinux.

Comment: @hendry please cite the relevant parts of /etc/exports and /etc/fstab on your ArchLinux server in your question.

Comment: I thought I mentioned it in the video earlier. Thanks again for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

From exports(5) - Linux man page

> secure
>   This option requires that requests originate on an Internet port less than IPPORT_RESERVED (1024). This option is on by default. To turn it off, specify insecure.

so you must use `insecure` to be able to mount a nfs share under non root user.

sample line from /etc/exports file

`/home/bogdan 192.168.1.10(rw,insecure,all_squash,anonuid=501,anongid=1000)`